# Why does clicking the questions tab provide a different view than on site load?

Tags: feature-request, tabs

The set of subtabs on site-load compared to the question's subtabs is confusingly different. I've only just recently figured out how to navigate back to the site-load view (and the various subtabs it contains) by click on the logo for that stackexchange. It seems to me that the site-load view should load to a default tab (perhaps 'questions') or give some visual "selected" cue by adding a 'home' tab (or the like).

Comment: "site load" == "home page"?

Comment: Yeah, but "home page" just doesn't feel like an adequate description though - but then we're just getting into semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a  visual indication of which tab is being shown: When none of the tabs is highlighted, you are watching the front page.

[image: Questions page]

[image: Front page]

For the new users, the problem is understanding that the site logo is the link for the front page. A way to resolve it would be displaying the logo using as background color the same color used to highlight the tabs. it is true that normally the logo is placed to the left side of the tabs, but that is not true for all the sites; this means that the logo could not seem as a special tab, in those sites.

[image: screenshot]

Probably a new tab would help the users, but I would rather not call it "Home"; "Front page" seems better, but I am not still convinced it is a good name.

I am used to sites where the logo is linked to the front page. It is true that in some of them there is also a tab for the front page, but that is something additional.
I would assume users are used to click on the site logo to return to the front page.

Comment: I am also used to sites where the logo links to the home page. My problem was mostly realizing that the home page content and the "question" tab content *were different*. Their layouts are exactly the same - the only visual cue you're on the home page is the lack of visual cues! I've been using this site for 3 years, and only now has the distinction become clear.

Comment: The front page contains the following tabs: interesting, featured, hot, week, and month. The Questions page contains the following tabs: newest, featured, faq, votes, active, and unanswered. I would not say the two pages are the same content. They list questions, but the structure is different.