# Upper left button of stack exchange communities vs. 'Questions' tab

Tags: support, meta, stack-exchange-button, tabs

I noticed, in the communities I'm subscribed to that if you click on the top left of the stackexchange community pull down menu, that it lists the questions of the community and when you click on 'Questions' in that community you get different questions.  Is there a difference in the two in the sorting of questions?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148079/why-does-clicking-the-questions-tab-provide-a-different-view-than-on-site-load

Comment: The fact that you got there by clicking through the communities list is incidental btw, it's simply the homepage vs /questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about clicking the site logo, or going to a site by clicking their name in the Stack Exchange dropdown, then that action will by default, take you to the 'active' tab (or, as @Cai said, the tab you last chose on that site):

[image]

This shows the questions that have been recently active, which includes edits, new questions and 'bumps' by community, in order of their activity (newest activity first).

Note: On Stack Overflow, if you have the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) enabled, it will take you to the 'home' tab by default instead.

---

Clicking the 'Questions' tab will by default take you to the 'newest' tab (or, again, the last tab you chose on that site):

[image]

This only shows questions in the order that they have been asked (newest first).

Comment: IIRC it actually takes you to the last tab you visited, the real question is why the homepage and /questions have different tabs and questions

Comment: @Cai just checked with Incognito, default is indeed Newest tab. (then you're right, it will remember your last selected tab.)

Comment: @Cai yeah that's true actually. it takes you to the active/newest tab only if you haven't changed it yourself